# How do I call lib file entry points that don't have underscore

Tags: visual-c++, openssl, linker

I'm using the pre-built binaries for OpenSSL Win64, and in the lib files they have methods such as SSL_write.
When I call SSL_write in my Visual C++ code and do a Build, the linker says it can't find
_SSL_write. Something added an underscore to the front. In ssl.h, it is declared as:

__owur int SSL_write(SSL *ssl, const void *buf, int num);

Any ideas how I can get this to build?

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so be kind. :-)